# Notifying Users of New Tweets in Android

Tags: android, twitter, notifications

I have designed an application to help corn farmers identify disease and bug problems to better care for their crops, and I have also integrated a Twitter feed that allows them to see the latest tweets of one of the local extension service agents. These tweets will let the farmers know of any local bug/disease problem that has been reported or is spreading so that the farmers can prepare themselves and hopefully fix their crops before the problem becomes serious.

What I'm wanting to know is how I can have my application check for new tweets and notify the user. I'm using "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json" to get the tweets, so I don't believe push notifications will work. Is this possible, or is there another way to check and notify users?

**tl;dr:** How can my app notify users of new tweets?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can check is to poll, but that isn't really recommended. You could also implement your own server, with some pub-sub mechanism.

But that said, Twitter recognizes this use case and offers [Streaming APIs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis). This will be the best way to implement what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the code below. May contain some syntax errors.

```
public class TwitterUpdater {
     Context context;
     public TwitterUpdate(Context ctx){
        context = ctx;
        Timer timer = new Timer;
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TwitterTask(), 0, 300000);
     }

}

public class TwitterTask extends TimerTask{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.loadMessages();
    }

}
public void loadMessages(){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;

           DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

           SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
           SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
           socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
           registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
           SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(client.getParams(), registry);
           DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, client.getParams());

           // Set verifier      
           HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);


        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=<Your twitter account name>");
        try {
          HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
          StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
          int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
          if (statusCode == 200) {

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              builder.append(line);
            }
            JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(builder.toString());
            if (obj.getClass() == JSONArray.class){
                JSONArray  results = obj;
                for(int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(i);

                    JSONObject user = result.getJSONObject("user");
                    if(((String) user.get("screen_name")).compareToIgnoreCase("TNCVB")== 0){
                        String name = user.getString("screen_name");
                        String text =result.getString("text");
                        String timestamp = result.getString("created_at");
                        //Put them in an object and add to array or something
                    }
                }
            }

                Intent nintent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, nintent, 0);

                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("Update")
                        .setContentIntent(pintent)
                        .setContentText("New messages are available.");
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(007, mBuilder.build());
          } else {
            Log.e("JSON Error:", "Failed to download file");
          }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }

    }
}
```